# cocos2d text to align at angle

Tags: iphone, text, cocos2d-iphone, label

I would like to know how to draw text/label at specific angle using cocos2d. 
eg. 30degree, 60degree, 125degree

thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw the text and rotate..

means:

mytext.rotation = 360..